# Very bad latency/lag playing local audio resource with Web Audio API in WKWebView and Safari

Tags: safari, wkwebview, game-development, web-audio-api

**Update:** I tried installing [howler](https://howlerjs.com/) and it seems to have resolved the initial play latency issue, however I am still unable to loop cleanly without a noticeable gap in the audio despite trying various settings and formats including wav.

---

I am writing a JavaScript based game and I am running to some extremely bad lag when playing audio (either mp3 or wav) inside a WKWebView using the Web Audio API.

When I run my game on Chrome on my desktop (Macbook) it behaves as expected with no noticeable delay when playing the audio.

Inside WKWebView on my iPhone however, as well as in Safari on desktop, there is an unacceptably long delay (~500 - 1000ms) after calling `play()` before the audio begins, even after multiple successive plays.

```
_ctx = new AudioContext();

load() {
    this._audio = new Audio();

    this._audio.oncanplaythrough = () => {
      console.log(`audio loaded ${this.src}`);
      this.loaded = true;
    };

    this._audio.preload = "auto";
    this._audio.src = this.src;
    this._audio.load();

    const ctx = this._ctx;
    this._track = ctx.createMediaElementSource(this._audio);
    this._track.connect(ctx.destination);
}

play() {
  try {
    const ctx = this._ctx;
    if (ctx.state === "suspended") {
      ctx.resume();
    }
    this._audio.currentTime = 0;
    this._audio.play();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`unable to play ${this}`, e);
  }
}
```

There is a similar problem with the `loop` property is set to true: on Chrome it loops seamlessly, but on Safari there is a similar delay before audio resumes after looping.

I'm starting to get worried because this will completely kill my game. It's unplayable with this much audio latency and I'm really hoping there is a solution to this. Bear in mind all my files are local resources accessed over the file system. Some solutions I've seen to load data into an `AudioBuffer`, but I can't find a way to do that with a local resource.

One strange thing I noticed is that on Safari desktop, every time I try to play the effect sound (a short wav), the media controller on my touchbar scrolls along with the sound as though I'm playing a video.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it in the most ridiculous way. As I alluded to, most every other answer out there involved loading data remotely using XHR, so out of an act of desperation I installed [Telegraph](https://github.com/Building42/Telegraph) in my native wrapper and pointed my webView at `127.0.0.1` and wouldn't you know it worked.

As for whether or not Apple will accept this as a valid practice is another question, and the irony is thick enough to cut: the fact that I am forced to host an actual HTTP server on the user's device *just* to get around the fact that local files are second-class citizens when it comes to data handling.